# NSUserDefaults registerDefaults with NSInteger

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, nsinteger

I am using `NSUserDefaults` to store some integer settings for my app, but I want to register default values for these settings, using code like this:

```
NSDictionary *appDefaults = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:(NSInteger)0, @"PMChordColour", (NSInteger)1, @"PMTextColour", (NSInteger)0, @"PMBackgroundColour", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];
```

The values are read in my app using

```
NSInteger setColour = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"PMChordColour"];
```

The problem with this is that `NSDictionary` does not allow scalar values to be stored.

Is there any way of registering defaults that allows integers to be stored? I realise that I could use `NSNumber` but it seems like unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you have to use `NSNumber`. It's *necessary* overhead.

Comment: I don't see how it is a necessary overhead to using `NSUserDefaults` when it handles `NSInteger` just fine. I could use an additional boolean value for "defaults set" and set them if false - no `NSNumber`. The only problem is with going through an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: @c.cam108 it's a convenience method -- note that in the case of numbers (esp. booleans), the system may return immortals. in that case, you'll have little other than retain/release cycles as 'overhead'.

Comment: @Justin sorry, I don't know what you mean by immortals. Can you expand on that please?

Comment: @c.cam108 np. `assert([NSNumber numberWithBool:0] == [NSNumber numberWithBool:0]);` will (likely) not abort because the implementation returns the same constant instances in these cases. they, like `NSString` literals, live for the life of the program. no allocation is required (unless the immortal is added to an autorelease pool, or some such thing).

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:13], @"id", nil];
int integer = [[dict objectForKey:@"id"] intValue];
```